# Swing JPanel repaint issue when it occurs while being on another gnome desktop

Tags: java, swing, gnome, repaint

I am facing a problem driving me nuts. I have a panel which I update this way :

- removeAll
- add new JComponents
- revalidate
- repaint

Most of the time, this works perfectly fine. However, if I switch to another gnome desktop (I tried on lxde, this is the same) **while a JDialog is showing**, the panel won't repaint properly.

**What I tried**

Adding this property on startup:

> -Dswing.bufferPerWindow=false

I tried calling the paint method on the panel directly, which is strongly discouraged.

Both methods result in messing arround with my components with transparent background. I see some pieces of other components which are at a total opposite location on my frame.

Here a piece of code to reproduce. Launch, switch to another desktop, wait for more than 3 seconds, and switch to first desktop. 2 lines are missing, and the first one is partially repaint.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    panel.add(new JLabel("Line 1"));
    panel.add(new JLabel("Line 2"));
    panel.add(new JLabel("Line 3"));

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    final JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
    dialog.add(new JLabel("Hello !"));
    dialog.pack();
    dialog.setVisible(true);

    // This executor simulate an incoming event I receive from another thread.
    final ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    executor.schedule(() -> {

      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        panel.removeAll();

        panel.add(new JLabel("Line 0000000 (new line !)"));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Line 1"));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Line 2"));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Line 3"));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Line 4 (new line !)"));

        panel.revalidate();
        panel.repaint();
      });

      executor.shutdown();
    }, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

  }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated ! Thanks !

Comment: Explain why are are using a ScheduledExecutorService  with invokeLater() when you can just use a swing [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#Timer(int,%20java.awt.event.ActionListener)) like this new Timer(3000,(action)->{...}).start(); for the same purpose?

Comment: Also why are you adding 5 labels to your panel every 3 seconds?  If you are trying to add multiple lines of text why not use a [JTextArea](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) and append multiple lines to your text area using [append](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append(java.lang.String))?

Comment: I'll look further into it when I see an attempt to change the components using a **`CardLayout`**. Check it out in the API and the tutorial.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Probably it's a driver (wayland/X11?) / java version / gnome version dependent issue. Also, really take a look at CardLayout as Andrew suggested, if your real application does the same kind of component replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) rather than `ScheduledExecutorService`.

```java
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main {
    private JPanel panel;

    private void buildAndDisplayGui() {
        Timer timer = new Timer(3000, this::timer);
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Line 1"));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Line 2"));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Line 3"));
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        final JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
        dialog.add(new JLabel("Hello !"));
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        timer.start();
    }

    private void timer(ActionEvent event) {
        panel.removeAll();
        panel.add(new JLabel("Line 0000000 (new line !)"));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Line 1"));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Line 2"));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Line 3"));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Line 4 (new line !)"));
        panel.revalidate();
        panel.repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main instance = new Main();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> instance.buildAndDisplayGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: I does work only because it will repaint the panel every 3 seconds. I used a scheduled executor to simulate an incoming event (one shot) from another thread. In that case, the jdialog seems to block the repaint of the panel behind.